# JBOSS EAP 5.1.1 error after installation

Tags: linux, jboss

After installing JBOSS EAP 5.1.1 on my Linux Server, I am getting following error when I run JBOSS with command run.sh

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /usr/lib/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as

JAVA: java

JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -server -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

CLASSPATH: /usr/lib/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/bin/run.jar

=========================================================================

**Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap**

Comment: Is this a virtual Linux server?

Answer (score 2):

http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html

The error seems to be saying that the virtual memory size of the machine is smaller than the maximum heap size we are defining via `Xms1303m -Xmx1303m`. I have changed it to `-Xms256m -Xmx512m` and it started working in my local Windows box.